# Replace a word using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace a word between two "bla bla"

mean I have a sentence - **He Was a "Bad boy".**
I want to replace **"Bad boy"** with **Good boy** with out ""

How to do it dynamically using java script Live example will be helpful.

Code I have tried

```
var str='He Was a "Bad boy".'; 
var n=str.match("");
```

Comment: look into `String#replace`

Comment: `var n = str.replace('Bad', 'Good')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str='He Was a "Bad boy" and "Bad boy".'; 
var n=str.replace(/\".*?\"/gi, 'Good Boy'); //g: globally, i: case-insensitive
console.log(n)
```

Edit:

`/\".*\"/` without `?` will match any chars in the quotes including the ending code, so it will match entire *Bad boy" and "Bad boy* since it is in the quotes. The trick it to use `?` to make the match less greedy.

Comment: It is only replacing first one is the sentence is like **var str='He Was a "Bad boy" and "Bad boy".'**;

Comment: @bumba you never said you wanted multiple replaces? Then `/.../g`

Comment: can u please replace the code with this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/82bvg/ please see this

Comment: @bumba just updated the answer, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the replace function.

```
'He Was a "Bad boy".'.replace('"Bad boy"', "Good boy")

//"He Was a Good boy."
```